# My Iptables block IP range not work

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I'm using `httpd` service on a Linux OS.

My result of `iptables -L`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:http recent: UPDATE seconds: 10 hit_count: 3 name: http_flood side: source 
           tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:http recent: SET name: http_flood side: source 
DROP       all  --  185.103.253.167      anywhere            
DROP       all  --  185.130.4.197        anywhere            
DROP       all  --  185.130.4.120        anywhere            
syn_flood  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 1/sec burst 1 
LOG        icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 1/sec burst 1 LOG level warning prefix `PING-DROP:' 
DROP       icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http 
DROP       all  --  108.162.222.0        anywhere            
DROP       all  --  66.249.0.0/16        anywhere            
DROP       all  --  108.162.222.0/24     anywhere            
DROP       all  --  162.158.176.0/24     anywhere            
DROP       all  --  108.162.221.0/24     anywhere
```

Please see at `DROP       all  --  66.249.0.0/16        anywhere`.

I had `sudo service iptables save` and `restart` but access log this IP still can send request to my server.

This is the access log:

```
66.249.71.130 - - [30/Jul/2016:19:18:39 +0700] "GET /zad_rgano/15330.htm HTTP/1.1" 404 37728
66.249.71.130 - - [30/Jul/2016:19:18:43 +0700] "GET /28060/szekntws/mmqmmxxmkgw/9768/45828_frftp_fqs_uxnenjp HTTP/1.1" 404 37674
66.249.79.144 - - [30/Jul/2016:19:18:46 +0700] "GET /38164/szekntws/mmqmmxxmkgw/9765/45828_frftp_fqs_uxnenjp HTTP/1.1" 404 37674
66.249.71.128 - - [30/Jul/2016:19:18:48 +0700] "GET /27501/szekntws/mmqmmxxmkgw/9756/45828_frftp_fqs_uxnenjp HTTP/1.1" 301 -
66.249.71.130 - - [30/Jul/2016:19:18:50 +0700] "GET /zaa_rgano/22063.htm HTTP/1.1" 404 37728
66.249.71.130 - - [30/Jul/2016:19:18:54 +0700] "GET /zae_rgano/18374.htm HTTP/1.1" 404 37728
66.249.71.130 - - [30/Jul/2016:19:18:56 +0700] "GET /29265/szekntws/mmqmmxxmkgw/9761/45828_frftp_fqs_uxnenjp HTTP/1.1" 404 37674
66.249.71.130 - - [30/Jul/2016:19:19:19 +0700] "GET /zac_rgano/16315.htm HTTP/1.1" 404 37728
66.249.71.130 - - [30/Jul/2016:19:19:22 +0700] "GET /index.php?kj=1&kjsite=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5rYW1pYmlqaW5zaG9wLnh5ei9pbmRleC5waHA/bWFpbl9wYWdlPXByb2R1Y3RfaW5mbyZwcm9kdWN0c19pZD0yNDQyOQ== HTTP/1.1" 200 110629
66.249.71.130 - - [30/Jul/2016:19:19:26 +0700] "GET /23989/szekntws/mmqmmxxmkgw/9754/45828_frftp_fqs_uxnenjp HTTP/1.1" 404 37845
66.249.71.130 - - [30/Jul/2016:19:19:29 +0700] "GET /zab_rgano/36033.htm HTTP/1.1" 404 37728
66.249.71.130 - - [30/Jul/2016:19:19:47 +0700] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Chuong-8-Tac-dong-cua-chinh-sach-thue.pdf HTTP/1.1" 200 496413
66.249.71.130 - - [30/Jul/2016:19:19:49 +0700] "GET /index.php?kj=1&kjsite=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5tc3N5c3RlbS54eXovaW5kZXgucGhwP21haW5fcGFnZT1wcm9kdWN0X2luZm8mcHJvZHVjdHNfaWQ9MzM3NzU= HTTP/1.1" 200 110586
66.249.79.144 - - [30/Jul/2016:19:19:47 +0700] "GET /index.php?kj=1&kjsite=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5rYW1pYmlqaW5zaG9wLnh5ei9pbmRleC5waHA/bWFpbl9wYWdlPXByb2R1Y3RfaW5mbyZwcm9kdWN0c19pZD0zOTE1NQ== HTTP/1.1" 200 110634
66.249.71.130 - - [30/Jul/2016:19:19:52 +0700] "GET /zaa_rgano/17556.htm HTTP/1.1" 404 37728
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`iptables` rules are read sequentially; as soon as a rule is found which applies, it is used; no further reading of the following rules is done.

In your case, the rule

```
DROP       all  --  66.249.0.0/16        anywhere
```

is **preceded** by

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http
```

This rule of course applies to *anyone*, and thus in particular it applies to the network `66.249.0.0/16`. So, being the first rule that applies to this network, it is indeed applied (sorry, no pun), and packets from the network are accepted by your firewall.

In order to ban the nasty networks, you will have to remove the rule

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http
```

and place it at the very bottom of the list, otherwise it will take precedence over your custom rules.

Comment: Can I ask one question: How I can config server only accept access by domain and block access by IP. I really really thanks about your help.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. The firewall knows nothing about domain names, only about IP addresses, so you cannot block by `name`, like, for instance, `facebook.com`. But I am not sure I understand what you mean...

Comment: My mean is "Client must access to my server by domain not by IP server Address.

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn you'd have to do that in your httpd, based on the content of the http `Host:` header.  More specifically, typically httpds are configured so that each virtual host responds to a set of domains, and then a "default" host matches everything that doesn't match the other virtual hosts.  You'd then want to configure the default host to reject traffic.